# to output the x,y,z values of accelerometer sensor to csv format using python

Tags: python, csv

I have been able to output the data into a csv file but the new values of x,y,z overwrite the previous values. I need to put those new values in next row.
I used following program for that purpose.
Its not a whole program but the part I am concerned with.

```
while(1):
   adxl345 = ADXL345()
   axes = adxl345.getAxes(True)
   print "ADXL345 on address 0x%x:" % (adxl345.address)
   print "   x = %.3fG" % ( axes['x'] )
   print "   y = %.3fG" % ( axes['y'] )
   print "   z = %.3fG" % ( axes['z'] )

   import csv
   myFile = open('data.csv', 'w')  
   with myFile:  
     myFields = ['x', 'y', 'z']
     writer = csv.DictWriter(myFile, fieldnames=myFields)    
     writer.writeheader()
     writer.writerow({'x' : axes['x'], 'y' : axes['y'], 'z' : axes['z']})
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Clearly when you open a file in `"w"` mode it will overwrite everything that was in that file before. So if you do not want to overwrite and just stick new values at the end of a file, you obviously need to open the file in `"a"` mode.

```
myFile = open('data.csv', 'a')
```

Hope my answer solved your question?.

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

> Modes 'r+', 'w+' and 'a+' open the file for updating (reading and writing); note that 'w+' truncates the file. Append 'b' to the mode to open the file in binary mode, on systems that differentiate between binary and text files; on systems that don’t have this distinction, adding the 'b' has no effect.

So your `open()` call truncates the file. You should open the wile using `a+` for appending to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You are opened the file object for writing mode 'w'
make it in append mode and check it. like this,

```
myFile = open('data.csv', 'a')
```